# Differential Operator McLaurin Series

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, fractional-calculus

The Non-Homogeneous Differential Equation

$$Ly=R$$
Where 
$$ L=F(D)= \sum_i a_iD^i $$

Is solved with the way below.

$$ Ly=R \Rightarrow y=\frac{R}{L}=\frac{R}{F(D)}$$

Then we expand the qiotient $ \frac{1}{F(D)}$ into Taylor Series in the neighborhood of 0 (McLaurin).

In order to expand F(D) we have to give $D=\frac{d}{dx} $ a value. How can we give a differential operator a value?

Comment: See Laplace transform where $D$ gets replaced by the "frequency" variable $s$.

Answer (score 2):

These are derived by the differential operator polynomial. Take one example, if we are going to solve the ODE with source term $R=e^x \cos(2x)$, then the followng substitution steps are probably what you are after.

\begin{align}
y'' - 2y' + 5y = e^x \cos(2x)\implies 
(D^2-2D+5)y=e^x \cos(2x)
\end{align}
To find the particular solution, we can divide the operator polynomial
\begin{align}
y_p&=\frac{1}{D^2-2D+5}~e^x~\cos(2x)\\
&=e^x~\frac{1}{(D+1)^2-2(D+1)+5}~\cos(2x)\\
&=\color{blue}{e^x~\frac{1}{D^2+4}~\cos(2x)}\\
&=e^x \Re\left\{e^{2ix}\frac{1}{(D+2i)^2+4}\right\}\\
&=e^x \Re\left\{e^{2ix}\frac{1}{(D+4i)}\frac{1}{D}\right\}\\
&=e^x \Re\left\{e^{2ix}\frac{1}{4i(1-\frac{Di}{4})}x\right\}\\
&=e^x \Re\left\{\frac{-ie^{2ix}}{4}\left(1+\frac{Di}{4}\right)x\right\}\\
&=e^x \Re\left\{\frac{-ie^{2ix}}{4}\left(x+\frac{i}{4}\right)\right\}\\
&=\frac{x}{4}~e^x~\sin(2x)+\frac{1}{16}e^x~\cos(2x)\\
\end{align}
where the second addend as a scaled source term is just a by-product of particular solution.
So the general solution is
\begin{align}
y(x)= e^x[ c_1\sin(2x)+ c_2\cos(2x)]~+~\frac{x}{4}~e^x~\sin(2x), \quad c_1,~c_2~\text{are constants.}
\end{align}

Note that the steps from the colored line are just for illustrations. In reality, one shall use the proved rules such as

$$\frac{1}{D^2+a^2}\cos ax=x\frac{1}{2D}\cos ax=\frac{x}{2a}\sin ax.$$

By the way, I started to learn the operators many years ago, but still have lots of puzzles to understand Heaviside's works.
Just found this might be helpful as well
[Solving ordinary differential equations using the differential operator D](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23425).