# Motivation for representation theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, book-recommendation, motivation

Next year I have choose a few optative courses from a big list, but syllabi are not available yet, so I have to make a choice based on names only.

I am thinking about taking one titled "Groups and representations". I have really enjoyed my Abstract Algebra courses so far, specially the part that covered Group theory. However, we never got into Representation theory, and I ignore what mathematical interest it might have.

I was wondering if someone could provide me with a text explaining what is representation theory about and what is the mathematical interest or motivation behind it. I have found some books on the topic, but they all just start giving definitions and theorems and never give a good introduction.

Comment: You are right that many sources are of that unfortunate traditional style "definition, lemma, proof", without explanation (and often without examples). And some _courses_ will be that. Some courses will be much better, but it's impossible to know from the title. Possibly from the identity of the instructor, and/or their course announcement. Of course, there is much more to say...

Comment: I think you mean "optional", not "optative"?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Probably! English is not my first language, sorry.

Comment: All you posters, with almost perfect English, except for maybe one missed word. It's hard to tell it's not your first language.  :-)

Comment: Group theorists study representation theory for the same reason ring theorists study modules: you learn more about an object by studying the things it acts on

Comment: [I made this short post on introducing it (with pictures!)](https://buraian.substack.com/p/visual-exposition-of-representation?utm_source=profile&utm_medium=reader2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard not to begin with a definition. To me, a (linear!) representation of a group $G$ on a vector space $V$ is a homomorphism $\varphi : G \longrightarrow GL(V).$ You can define, i.e. phrase it differently via group actions but the homomorphism picture already illustrates the answer to your question: $$\varphi (g\cdot h)\stackrel{(*)}{=}\varphi (g)\cdot\varphi (h).$$ We transport the usually very abstract group multiplication among its elements into a multiplication of matrices, of linear functions. We usually can handle matrices far better than group multiplications. We have with linear algebra a mighty tool to investigate the right-hand-side of $(*)$ while the left-hand-side could be as abstract as e.g. $G=\langle a,b\,|\,a^2=aba=1 \rangle.$ If the representation is furthermore faithful, i.e. $\ker \varphi =\{1\},$ then we even have matrices that represent the group elements one-to-one. That's why we investigate group representations: we know how to deal with matrices. The homomorphism tells us what we can switch to the left what we have learned on the right (of (*)).

Comment: Your presentation isn't so abstract. Since $$b=a^2ba^2=a(aba)a=a^2=1,$$ the group it defines is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: Yes, I know. I have written it without thought. After I had this thought and considered making it more complicated, I had a second thought: It actually emphasizes my statement. Yes, I have defined $\mathbb{Z}_2.$ But imagine how more obvious it would have been if I had written $G=\langle \begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix} \rangle$!

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried googling to find motivatations for the subject?  Some are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622/importance-of-representation-theory), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70312/importance-of-group-representation-theory?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [here](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/210BPage/handouts/repthy.pdf).  Historical background for the subject is [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/articles/groupdet.pdf). The question that first led Frobenius to develop representation theory of finite groups has always struck me as a bad motivation for the subject. Keep in mind that one person's inspiring motivation is someone else's dull problem or excessive technicality.

**Example**. When I first saw representation theory, I did not understand why it was worthwhile. The accessible applications that I heard about to pure group theory (proving the $p^aq^b$ theorem and  showing nonexistence of simple groups of some peculiar size) felt  uninspiring. What sold me on the utility of representation theory of finite groups was learning about Artin's creation of $L$-functions of representations of Galois groups, and how they lead to a decomposition of zeta-functions of Galois extensions of $\mathbf Q$ that generalizes the simpler decomposition of zeta-functions of quadratic fields and cyclotomic fields into products of Dirichlet $L$-functions. Reread the last sentence of my first paragraph, however.

Comment: Yes, indeed, there are many "orthodox" reasons to pay attention to "representation theory" (whatever that is), but/and, also, it is also _explanatory_ and _helpful_, which is not always mentioned. That is, it does not merely make up and solve _new_ problems, but, rather, helps us resolve _prior_ issues. :)