# Find the Stabilizer and Orbit

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

Can someone explain how these answers were derived? I have trouble with understanding the concepts of doing this sort of problem. I know the stabilizer is that which brings the element to itself. I am confused on what the orbit is ($\text{orb}_G (i)=\{\alpha(i)|\alpha\in G\}$).

Comment: You have a group $G$ and a set $S$. Let $i \in S$. The orbit of $i$ with respect to $G$ is the subset of elements in $S$ that can be reached by applying a member of $G$ to $i$.

Comment: are you able to explain how the stabilizer and orbit of the elements above are obtained? i am not seeing it

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253179/intuitive-definitions-of-the-orbit-and-the-stabilizer ?  How can you know the definitions of orbit and stabilizer and yet not be able to identify their elements? It's a little contradictory...

Answer (score 1):

Given a set of symmetries $G$ acting on a set $X$ of symbols, one of which is $x$:

To find the stabilizer of $x$: for all $g\in G$, compute $g\cdot x$. If $g\cdot x=x$, write down $g$. When you are done, you have the stablizer of $x$.

To find the orbit of $x$: for all $g\in G$, compute $g\cdot x$. Write down the resulting element of $X$ if you have not seen it previously. At the end, you have the orbit of $x$.

What I have written here is nothing more than a verbose regurgitation of the definition of the two sets.