# Group Actions on $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups

We are learning about Quotient spaces, and group actions. For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We know that the function $G(n)=\{A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}:A^TA=1\}$ is a group action on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I am struggling to see  what the actual orbits are, and why $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash G(n)$ is homeomorphic to the positive real line. These are given as fact, but I dont see why these are elementary results.

Comment: Have you tried this for $n=2$?

Comment: Your second sentence has some sloppy mathematical grammar. $G(n)$ is a collection of matrices, not a function. It describes (the underlying set of) a group, but you haven't described how it acts on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: You might want to check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253179/intuitive-definitions-of-the-orbit-and-the-stabilizer

Comment: the action is always "multiplication", as in if $G$ acts on $X$, then the action is the map $x\to gx$? Is this wrong?

Comment: @user593295 I suggest that you read the wikipedia page on group actions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action   .    There are a lot of nice examples there.