# Group theory: group actions on finite group.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

I'm having trouble with the following question:
Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a finite set $X$. For $g\in G$, let $Fix_X(g) =\{x\in X \mid xg = x\}$ and, for $x\in X$, let $G_x = \{g\in G \mid xg = x\}$.
Prove that
$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum\limits_{g\in G} |Fix_X(g)|$ is the number of orbits of $X$ under $G$.

[Hint: let $P = \{(x, g) \mid xg =
x\} \subseteq X\times G$ and do a double count: calculate the number $\frac{|P|}
{|G|}$ as a sum over $X$ and as a sum over $G$.]

Using the hint I have got that $\frac{|P|}{|G|}=\frac{\sum\limits_{g\in G} |Fix_X(g)|}{|G|}=\frac{\sum\limits_{x\in X} |G_x|}{|G|}$ and have replaced the $\frac{|G_x|}{|G|}$ for each $x$ by $\frac{1}{|O_G(x)|}$. 
After here I'm stuck. Could someone please point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition on the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242968/intuition-on-the-orbit-stabilizer-theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done. Your right hand side is 
$$\sum_{x\in X} \frac{1}{|O(x)|}=\sum_{\mbox{orbits}}\sum_{x\in O} \frac{1}{|O(x)|} = \mbox{number of orbits},$$ since the sum over every orbit gives you one.

Comment: ( \mbox, eh? That's a new one to me… )

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand how the two are equal? Is it because $X$ is the disjoint union of the orbits?

Comment: Figured it out now, cheers.