# Why is the Orbit Stabiliser Theorem intuitively true?

Tags: group-theory, intuition, group-actions

Why is the OST intuitively true? (Specially for the finite groups but also infinite groups) I understand the proof and the steps, but it is not obvious to me like let’s say Intermediate Value theorem.

Comment: Do any of these answers help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242968

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition on the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242968/intuition-on-the-orbit-stabilizer-theorem)

Answer (score 0):

The theorem is one of the many examples for [The homomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms).
Many people see this as intuitive, as it is in many examples.
There are versions of this theorem for groups, rings, vector spaces, sets, etc., much more then just the few given on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by the assertion in your first sentence, but for example the Orbit Stabilizer Theorem is *not* a corollary of the Homomorphism Theorem: the latter is concerned with normal subgroups, the former with arbitrary subgroups.

Comment: @LeeMosher No, I don't mean that it follows from the H. theorem. It is just a different version. The proof of the orbit stabilizer theorem and the homomorphism theorem are quite similar, just like the homomorphism theorem for vector spaces, sets, rings, etc. Therefore I said that it belongs together. Some textbooks introduce a very general case first (homomorphism theorem for maps between arbitrary sets, discussing the partition formed by preimages) and then everything else is just an application of that one.